# On SIGWX (significant weather) charts, what does **/** mean?

Tags: weather, aeronautical-charts, symbology

On SIGWX charts, it shows pairs of symbols with, say, `*/**` or `**/**`. I know what the symbols mean on either side, but why are there two, and what does the slash indicate?

Would love good resources that explain more, too.

Example chart here, from [the FAA sample questions](http://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_questions/media/sport_rec_private_akts.pdf) (caution: 37 MB download), Figure 20, over Southern California.

I’m also interested in knowing what a dot with `R` underneath means.

[image: Example chart]

Answer (score 7):

http://www.beyourowncaptain.com/downloads/files/Reading%20Prog%20Charts.pdf
http://aviationweather.gov/static/adds/docs/metars/wxSymbols_anno1.pdf

Asterisks are snow, dots are rain. The slash means a mixture of the two.

[image]

The dot with an R under it is a substitution for the the thunderstorm symbol.

[image]

What you're looking at isn't a *real* SIGWX chart, it's a testing figure.

Comment: if it’s a mixture, then why do they show (actual example from chart) `**/**`? You can’t have a mixture of the same thing.

Comment: Can you link to the chart?

Comment: http://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_questions/media/sport_rec_private_akts.pdf (caution: 37 MB download), Figure 20, over Southern California

Comment: added a picture of the chart in my question

Comment: Honestly, I believe it's a mistake. I have found 3 sources confirming that means mix precipitation. One of them is the Aviation Weather Services advisory circular. You can see here, on page 8-3 http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC-0045G_chg1_fullDocument.pdf

Comment: Jungroth: hmmm, interesting! Thanks for digging out the source material. It’s a bit strange because the `**/**` occurs quite a few times in the chart!

Comment: @Peter I recall seeing `**/**` on my written test too - I can't think of any time where I've seen it on a *real* SIGWX chart though, and as I recall there were no questions in the question bank about the "mix of the same thing" precip areas (this might have changed though).