# What does this wind symbol mean?

Tags: usa, weather

At https://www.aviationweather.gov on the Forecasts puldown, then the Aviation Forecasts selection, the chart opens and often shows what looks like a letter R with a tail in the lower right, in different colors.  The legend does show the symbol. What does it indicate?

[image: weather symbol]

Comment: related, with possibly the answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3037/1467

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Info button (top right) takes you to an explanation site, which in turn links you to

https://www.AviationWeather.gov/metar/symbol

Which explains the Symbol (under the section *Fog or special weather*) as **Thunderstorm**

Comment: Excellent!  I guess I need to poke around there more, I hadn't even tried the Info pages at all. Thanks.